# Using generic interface in a generic class

Tags: c#, list, generics, interface

How force to use class that implement generic interface in class?
Is something like this possible?

```
public interface IGeneric<T>
{
    T Value {get;}
}

//public class MyList<IGeneric<T>> {}//not allowed
```

Comment: I assume you want something like `class MyList<T> : IGeneric<T>`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Comment: No i dont want to implement interface, but use on my custom list as items.

Comment: Then the first option from Enigmativities answer is your solution

Comment: It is possible to create such a class, but I cannot create instances of this class. [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/97UWgT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    MyList<string> myList = new MyList<string>(new Generic());
}

public interface IGeneric<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class MyList<T>
{
    private IGeneric<T> _generic;
    public MyList(IGeneric<T> generic)
    {
        _generic = generic;
    }
}

public class Generic : IGeneric<string>
{
    public string Value => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Or like this:

```
void Main()
{
    MyList<Generic, string> myList = new MyList<Generic, string>();
    //Or MyList<IGeneric<string>, string> myList = new MyList<IGeneric<string>, string>();
}

public interface IGeneric<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class MyList<G, T> where G : IGeneric<T>
{
}

public class Generic : IGeneric<string>
{
    public string Value => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: I can't create class instance, compiler Error CS0311. 
`code 
 MyList<IGeneric<string>> myList = new MyList<IGeneric<string>>();
`

Comment: Probably `myList` needs to have type `MyList<string>`, but if you can edit your current interface + class + `myList` declaration into the question we can answer more specifically.

Comment: `MyList<string>` don't work. I don't understand "edit your ... declaration to the question".
[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/97UWgT)

Comment: @JarosławPietras - I've fleshed it out more. And tested that the code runs.